# Bash: weird parse output?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm working on a simple script that accepts multiple command line arguemnts in an order:

```
#!/bin/bash

function arg_parser () {
while [[ $# != 0 ]] ; do
  case "$1" in
    --one)
      varone="$2"
      ;;
    --two)
      vartwo="$2"
      ;;
    --three)
      varthree="$2"
      ;;
    --four)
      varfour="$2"
      ;;
    --five)
      varfive="$2"
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done
}

arg_parser "$@"

echo $varone
echo $vartwo
echo $varthree
echo $varfour
echo $varfive
```

Then run it:

```
./test.sh --one testone --three testthree --two testtwo --five "test five" --four "$$$$"
testone
testtwo
testthree
793793
test five
```

Notice how `--four` returns "793793" and not "$$$$"? Does anyone know why this is happening and/or how the script can be improved to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Your quoting is broken: that is Process ID (PID) of the script itself.

Comment: sorry, where is it broken exactly?

Comment: `"` expands the variable `$$`: you want single quotes: `'`.

Comment: oooh, i see. so this cant be resolved in the script to make it possible to use `"$$$$"` as an argument?

Comment: The expansion happens before it is passed to your script. You have to use single quotes `'$$$$'` if you want literal `$` characters passed to your script.

Comment: You'll also want to `shift 2` because otherwise you're going through the `case` statement twice as many times as you need to.

Answer (score 0):

`$$` is a special variable that expands to the process id of the shell, in this case on the command line before your script even starts. Try something like `echo $$`. You'll need to escape the dollar signs with backslashes or put them in single quotes to not have them expand, i.e. `echo '$$$$'`.

The double quotes don't help, they'll just prevent word splitting of the expanded value, just like with regular variables (`$foo` vs. `"$foo"`).

Also, in your loop, you `shift` only once even in the cases where you use the second argument too. This means that the arguments to your options are also processed as options themselves:

```
$ ./test.sh --one --two --three --four --five xyz
--two
--three
--four
--five
xyz
```

If you don't want that, you'll need to `shift` an additional time after using `$2`:

```
while [[ "$#" != 0 ]] ; do
  case "$1" in
    --one)
      varone="$2"
      shift
      ;;
    --two)
      vartwo="$2"
      shift
      ;;
    # ...
  esac
  shift
done
```